# C ENUM Not Recognizing In Xcode iOS Dev Project

Tags: ios, c, xcode, enums

Is there a Build Setting to allow normal C enums to work in Xcode? Please don't tell me to use typedef techniques. I need to use straight up old fashion enums. I have a legacy project that uses them just fine, but when I import the classes into a new project, it throws errors saying my enums are undefined.

I use a simple Global.h to include them in all the complaining classes. My implementation is extremely basic:

```
enum {
state1,
state2
};
```

Clues?

Comment: Can you give an example of where you are using the enum, as well as the compiler error(s)?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while and I don't have a c compiler on my iPad to test it, but try:

```
enum states {
state1,
state2
};
```

Comment: I actually found a sample project from the book "Learning iOS Game Programming" under the project title SLQTSOR that uses this legacy method in its Global.h. No enum tag. No typedef method, and it appears to compile and run perfectly. I keep thinking its a compiler setting.

Comment: The C99 setting is always one to play with if some C code compiles and some doesn't.

Comment: I just verified that your code does compile on an old FreeBSD system using gcc. You could also check that your compiler is gcc and not llvm.

Comment: Yeah the entire thing is strange. I switched everything in my project to typedef enum and the problem persists. It really feels like Xcode is incredibly fragile. A project works for a while until you try to import to new classes, then something breaks, and there is no return.

Comment: To make matters ever weirder, I created a new project, wired in the Global.h with the typedef enums, and it still throws the compiling error. I feel like Rod Serling is standing behind me about to introduce tonight's episode.

Comment: Oh, well that could be useful. Is there anywhere you can post the new sample project, with perhaps a trimmed down Global.h that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I'll give you an easier scenario. I create a new project (single view iOS app, no ARC, no storyboards, only iPhone). I immediately add a Global.h to the root directory as a C++ header file. I add typedef enum { kMyVar } myVars ; to the header. I then #import "Global.h" to the AppDelegate (Xcode immediately finds the file and completes the code for me). Then it immediately complains that it can't find the file. WTH? I restart Xcode and it works. Unfortunately, this isn't helping my main project file.

Comment: Okay, fixed my main project. Not sure why the new one didn't work. This was idiotic. I had created a "global.h" prior to creating the "Global.h" I had Xcode "remove references" when deleting the lowercase version. It didn't. When I COMMAND-Clicked the "Global.h" reference, it went to the old file that should have been removed. I then hand deleted it, and retyped the import line. It then made the connect, and the old school enums worked. Blimey!!!!!!!! Thank you all for the help. You guys were great.